# Which unsupervised algorithm we can use to detect anomaly in transaction data?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I was trying to look for an algorithm which can be used to find anomalies in transaction data which also contains Timestamp as one of the columns. I tried using Isolation forest but I think it's not possible to use it with the DateTime column Or is it possible to use isolation forest?? Well, I'm new to machine learning, so seeking some help here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are different algorithms. I don't know for which one you can have timestamps, but in addition to the isolation forest there is the principal component analysis and the clustering.